# How can I put additional parameters inside find command with exec?

Tags: linux, git-bash

My command looks approximately like this:

```
find path/*.log -mtime -7 -exec grep "string" {} >> file.txt \;
```

To save some lines, i wanted to put a `cut` command already inside it → `| cut -d '"' -f 6`, but all I get are errors however i try to fit it there.

Comment: Why would it _save some lines_ if you _put a `cut` command already inside_? It's still only one line if you write `find path/*.log -mtime -7 -exec grep "string" {} \; | cut -d '"' -f 6 >> file.txt`.

Comment: I meant saving lines in script where i would have to read the file again within while loop. This is what I was looking for, thanks.